# how to drop ceph osd block?

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I build a ceph cluster with kubernetes and it create an osd block into the `sdb` disk.
I had delete the ceph cluster but cleanup all the kubernetes instance which were created by ceph cluster, but it did't delete the osd block which is mounted into sdb.

[image]

I am a beginner in kubernetes. How can I remove the osd block from `sdb`.
And why the osd block will have all the disk space?

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to remove osd block from disk on ubuntu18.04:

Use this command to show the logical volume information:

`$ sudo lvm lvdisplay`

Then you will get the log like this:

[image]

Then execute this command to remove the osd block volumn.

`$ sudo lvm lvremove <LV Path>`

Check if we have removed the volume successfully.

`$ lsblk`